# Wikipedia pdf generator, how to solve "wide tables" issue

Tags: web-scraping, pdf-generation, wikipedia, tabular

I need to print a wide table from page on Wikipedia. The article uses the Thai alphabet for a table of Thai vowels. When I generate PDF there's only a part of table. Only solution I see is download page (html source code), extract, delete everything I don't need and then print the table. Does someone know better approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried saving this article as PDF from Chrome, and the tables looked fine. The PDF generated by Chrome does not exhibit the same problems as the one generated by Wikipedia.

You can access Chrome's PDF generation functionality through the `Print` menu.